# I am using List View for searching purpose, how to get the selected item position on List View?

Tags: android, listview

here i uses two Arrays to get the item id for each selected item, but i didn't get the correct position of item on list view. 
if i search and select an item ie:"MacBook Air" the search result shows the item as in first position and i get the position=1, but actually i need the position=9.
how to get the correct position of array item?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lv;
EditText acc_no;
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
String products[] = {"Dell Inspiron", "HTC One X", "HTC Wildfire S", "HTC Sense", "HTC Sensation XE",
        "iPhone 4S", "Samsung Galaxy Note 800",
        "Samsung Galaxy S3", "MacBook Air", "Mac Mini", "MacBook Pro"};
String productid[]={"12","45","95","18","45","77","66","11","74","33","44"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    acc_no = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.acc_no_editText);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.list_item, products);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    lv.setVisibility(GONE);
    acc_no.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            lv.setVisibility(GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(acc_no.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
                lv.setVisibility(GONE);
            }else{
                lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                MainActivity.this.arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            acc_no.setText(lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, productid[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            lv.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: search your selected item in your original list using acc_no or any other desired field

Comment: i didn't get you sorry..

Comment: you will be having a original list from which you are filtering your records. So from your selected position on list click search the selected item in your main list taking search parameter from your selected item like for now you have `acc_no`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

guys i solved my problem.. **Thank you** all.. who tried to help me.. :).

i used a function

```
public int indexOfString(String searchString, String[] domain)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < domain.length; i++)
        if(searchString.equals(domain[i])){
            return i;
        }
    return -1;
}
```

which returns the correct string item position from the `products[]`, and using that position i got the corresponding item from `productId[]`.

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String item=lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            acc_no.setText(item);
            int ArrayPosition=indexOfString(item,products);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, productid[ArrayPosition], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            lv.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
    });
}
public int indexOfString(String searchString, String[] domain)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < domain.length; i++)
        if(searchString.equals(domain[i])){
            return i;
        }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this you should use array adapter for getting item because list view fills from start after you search so use adapter for it,
in your lv.setonItemClick

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        acc_no.setText(arrayadapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: actually i need the "productid[position]" of the corresponding selected item. if the list view fills from starts then, is there any way to get the correct position of item in array adapter?

Comment: yes, but there is no such method "arrayAdapter.getItemAtPosition"

Answer (score 0):

You could store the two arrays as a dictionary as in 
`HashMap<String, Integer> productIdPairs` 
and do a quick `productIdPairs.get()` when you click on an item.